# Node.js script freezes when using MySQL with Socket.io without crashing

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-mysql, node-mssql

I'm a supernovice to Node.js, coming from a PHP background, but I'm currently working on a project that requires some kind of open communication between web server and browser.

The script is meant to emit two sets of data: a list of the scheduled staff that's been matched with a list of clocked in staff, and a set of data related to vehicle status.  For reasons beyond my control, the scheduled staff and vehicle data is located on a MySQL server and the clocked in data is located on a separate MsSQL server.

The issue I'm having is that while the script does what it's meant to do, after a certain amount of time (sometimes minutes, sometimes over a day) it ceases to do anything.  The setInterval timers for the functions stop and it stops serving the client-side socket.io.js page.

I think it's the way I'm managing my SQL connections but I'm not entirely sure and even if I was, I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong here.  No errors are printing to console.  I've spent hours trying to find a solution but haven't been able to find anything that matches my circumstance.

Here is the code in its entirety (changed SQL connection info for security reasons).

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    forceNew: true
});
var moment = require('moment');
var mssql = require('mssql');
var mssql_connection = new mssql.ConnectionPool({
    pool: {
        max: 10
    },
    server: 'hostname',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
});
mssql_connection.connect();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mysql_connection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 20,
    host: 'hostname',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    red.end();
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


// Create function to refresh all data that must be grabbed every 5 seconds.

function refreshSchedule() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {


        try {

            mysql_connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {


                // Query MySQL database for timepunch entries matching MsSQL results.
                connection.query('SELECT * FROM view_schedule WHERE active = 1 AND start <= ' + moment().format("X") + ' AND finish > ' + moment().format("X") + ' ORDER BY job,start ASC', function (err, mysql_result, fields) {

                    if (err) {
                        connection.release();
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    resolve(mysql_result);


                });

            });


        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }


    });
}

function refreshTimeclock(schedule) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var timestamp = moment().format("X") - (60 * 60 * 12);

        const request = new mssql.Request(mssql_connection);
        request.query('SELECT SCHDHISTID,DATETIMESTART,DATETIMEEND,PERSID,PERSCODE,LNAME,FNAME FROM dbo.VWSCHDHIST WHERE DATETIMESTART >= \'' + moment(timestamp, "X").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS") + '\'', (err, mssql_result) => {
            if (err) {
                connection.release();
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            var process_schedule = schedule;
            var process_timepunch = mssql_result.recordset;


            var output = [];

            for (i = 0; i < process_schedule.length; i++) {

                process_schedule[i].fullname = process_schedule[i].fullname.replace(" (NTD)", "");
                process_schedule[i].fullname = process_schedule[i].fullname.replace(" (ND)", "");
                process_schedule[i].fullname = process_schedule[i].fullname.replace(" (NT)", "");
                process_schedule[i].fullname = process_schedule[i].fullname.replace(" (Maint)", "");
                process_schedule[i].fullname = process_schedule[i].fullname.replace(" ^^", "");
                process_schedule[i].fullname = process_schedule[i].fullname.replace(" (Jr./NTD)", "");

                for (j = 0; j < process_timepunch.length; j++) {

                    if (process_schedule[i].fullname == (process_timepunch[j].FNAME + " " + process_timepunch[j].LNAME)) {

                        process_schedule[i].punchin = moment(process_timepunch[j].DATETIMESTART, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS").format("X");
                        if (process_timepunch[j].DATETIMEEND) {

                            process_schedule[i].punchout = moment(process_timepunch[j].DATETIMEEND, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS").format("X");

                        } else {

                            process_schedule[i].punchout = null;

                        }

                    }

                }
                output.push(process_schedule[i]);

            }
            resolve(output);


        });

    });

}

function refreshVehicles() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {


        try {

            mysql_connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

                // Query MySQL database for timepunch entries matching MsSQL results.
                connection.query('SELECT * FROM data_vehicles WHERE number > 0', function (err, mysql_result, fields) {
                    if (err) {
                        connection.release();
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    resolve(mysql_result);


                });

            });


        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }


    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    refreshSchedule().then(function (result) {
        refreshTimeclock(result).then(function (output) {
            console.log("Schedule: " + moment().format("HH:mm:ss"));
            io.emit('updateSchedule', output);
        });
    });
}, 15000);

setInterval(function () {
    refreshVehicles().then(function (output) {

        console.log("Vehicles: " + moment().format("HH:mm:ss"));
        io.emit('updateVehicles', output);

    });
}, 15000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Any help is appreciated, even just a point in the right direction might help at this point.

Comment: You should call connection.release(); always, your only calling if error

Comment: Just added connection.release(); inside each connection.query() function.  Script is running and emitting data for now (although time will tell if that resolves the issue) but I keep getting an error message on the console: `"(node:24566) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Resource not currently part of this pool".`  Is it where I put the connection.release()?

Comment: The `request.query('SELECT SCHDHISTID` query, your closing with  `connection.release();` but that not the mysql pool, probable want `request.release();` or eqivalant for that lib

Comment: The script ran for about 40 minutes and ended up hanging up again.  Interestingly, the hang up this time was triggered when I reloaded the client-side webpage through the browser.  It loaded the page including the socket.io.js script once, the script froze, and then it stopped serving up the client-side file immediately.  EDIT:  Let me try again with your other comment.

Comment: Its failing the Promise and because your not resolving/rejecting only returning its hanging waiting for the promise to resolve, use reject(err) in your errors

Comment: I updated the mssql function to run mssql.close() which is the equivalent of release.  Also changed all the isntances of return to reject(err).  Still the same issues, usually within seconds of starting the script.  No error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above was a mess and I did clean it up a lot during the process of troubleshooting it, but at the end of it all the problem continued.

Eventually setup a Node.js server at home and it did not reproduce the same issue.  I eventually realized that the issue was on my hosting provider's end (Dreamhost).  I've since moved the Node.js components over to DigitalOcean and it's been running fine for days.